# Change WebService Proxy URL in Visual Studio .NET 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, proxy-classes

I've created a WebService Proxy from a given URL, but at runtime a need to change this URL depending of some conditions.

How to do it?

I've searched on the web and founded that I should change the "Url" property. But, some how, this property isn't exposed in my proxy class.

I am using Visual Studio .NET 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the "classic" SOAP web service proxy (created like this: http://alexduggleby.com/2008/08/24/add-web-reference-instead-of-service-reference-in-visual-studio-2008/), it really has an `URL` property.

If you are using Service references as in "new" WCF web services, take a look at this SO post: [How to consume WCF web service through URL at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193124/how-to-consume-wcf-web-service-through-url-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.Url = <new Url>
```

Or if you want it configurable, the classical way was: set the web service reference: URL Behavior to dynamic and set it at the config file as mentioned in :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx