# How to initialize wcf client with particular Url Address?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I remember with ASMX there was an easy solution:

```
 MyAsmxServiceClient serviceClient = 
     new MyAsmxServiceClient("http://myServiceLocation/myService.asmx");
```

How can achieve the same with WCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually done in the app.config/web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            address="http://myServiceLocation/myService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="IMyServiceContract" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

or you [could also do it programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx) if you prefer.

Normally when you generate the client side proxy using the [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) it will also create a sample `output.config` file containing all you need to setup the configuration.

---

UPDATE:

You could also provide names to your endpoints:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            name="foo"
            address="http://foo.com/myService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="IMyServiceContract" />
        <endpoint
            name="bar"
            address="http://bar.com/myService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="IMyServiceContract" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and then:

```
using (var client = new MyClientProxy("foo"))
{
    var result = client.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: Ok this looks good by what I really need to do is this: if(x) service = new Service("http://x") else service = new Service("http://y"), so is there a way to define 2 endpoints for the same contract and retrieve them by name or something?

Comment: @The Chad Who Loved Me, yes you can. I have updated my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 4):

On the same lines, binding = binding type you are using

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8888/MyService");        
MyServiceClient sv= new MyServiceClient(binding, address)
```

Comment: How do I initialize the binding object?

Comment: Updated above assuming you are using BasicHttpBinding. Hope it helps.

Comment: No that did not work unfortunately, the exception was something along the lines with the client is in the faulty state.

Comment: refer this, which I came across while searching more on this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193124/how-to-consume-wcf-web-service-through-url-at-run-time