# How to make a UWP that will work with the default WCF Service application

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, xaml, win-universal-app

If you create a new project, WCF Service Application C#, it makes a web service and starts it up.

But there is no information on how to actually communicate with it from a client, or how to even write that.

What does the UWP client look like which will communicate with that service?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1193135/1136211).

Comment: That's not what I mean.  An example of a UWP that can call that GetData function.  I don't get anything to work. I can't even manually get an answer by typing in the browser with their service running.

Comment: That answer should get you going in the right direction.  In short, you need to create a client that can call the web service.   The way to do that is outlined in the answer Clemens linked to.

Comment: Nope.  The question is perfectly clear. Write an endpoint to the Microsoft default project.  No links. Post your code.

Comment: @jockey4her - It doesn't seem clear to me.   The functionality for accessing a SOAP web service (WCF) is the same whether you're doing it from a console app, a WinForms, Web Forms or UWP or whatever.   That's the whole idea behind web services - interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make a UWP that will work with the default WCF Service application

1. Create a default WCF Service application and start it up as you have already did.
2. Create a Universal Windows Blank App by following [Create a "Hello, world" app (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal) in the same solution.
3. Add service reference for your universal app [image]
4. Click Discover, it will default find the wcf service in your solution.Change the namespace to meet your requirement.[image]
5. Add following code to a button click event handle.Then run uwp you will see the `GetData` Result.

   ```
   private async void BtnConnectWcf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       ToDoService.Service1Client client = new ToDoService.Service1Client();       
       await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(client.GetDataAsync(10).Result.ToString()).ShowAsync();
       await client.CloseAsync();
   }
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, but it was not very clear.  Add Service Reference menu does not appear like in your picture.  I happen to stumble on it by accident, by clicking not the Solution, but the project, then Add, then found it down further in the list.  After that this answer works.