# Why is Add Service Reference not generating the same code in UWP?

Tags: web-services, wcf, uwp

I am trying to call FedEx's rate service. On their sample app, their reference.cs implements RateService():

```
amespace RateWebServiceClient.RateServiceWebReference {
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.6.1038.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="RateServiceSoapBinding", Namespace="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v22")]
public partial class RateService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getRatesOperationCompleted;

    private bool useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RateService() {
        this.Url = "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate";
        if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
            this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
        }
        else {
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
        }
    }
```

When I generate it on my project, I get completely different code. I noticed I never saw the old fashion web services option.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool. 
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// 
// This code was auto-generated by   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceReference.Platforms, version 15.0.26919.1
// namespace Carriers.FedExServiceReference {   

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v22", ConfigurationName="FedExServiceReference.RatePortType")]
public interface RatePortType {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v22/getRates", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Carriers.FedExServiceReference.getRatesResponse> getRatesAsync(Carriers.FedExServiceReference.getRatesRequest request);
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2556.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v22")]
public partial class RateRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private WebAuthenticationDetail webAuthenticationDetailField;

    private ClientDetail clientDetailField;

    private TransactionDetail transactionDetailField;

    private VersionId versionField;

    private bool returnTransitAndCommitField;

    private bool returnTransitAndCommitFieldSpecified;

    private CarrierCodeType[] carrierCodesField;

    private ServiceOptionType[] variableOptionsField;

    private ConsolidationKey consolidationKeyField;

    private RequestedShipment requestedShipmentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public WebAuthenticationDetail WebAuthenticationDetail {
        get {
            return this.webAuthenticationDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.webAuthenticationDetailField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("WebAuthenticationDetail");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public ClientDetail ClientDetail {
        get {
            return this.clientDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.clientDetailField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ClientDetail");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public TransactionDetail TransactionDetail {
        get {
            return this.transactionDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionDetailField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetail");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
    public VersionId Version {
        get {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.versionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Version");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
    public bool ReturnTransitAndCommit {
        get {
            return this.returnTransitAndCommitField;
        }
        set {
            this.returnTransitAndCommitField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ReturnTransitAndCommit");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ReturnTransitAndCommitSpecified {
        get {
            return this.returnTransitAndCommitFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.returnTransitAndCommitFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ReturnTransitAndCommitSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CarrierCodes", Order=5)]
    public CarrierCodeType[] CarrierCodes {
        get {
            return this.carrierCodesField;
        }
        set {
            this.carrierCodesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CarrierCodes");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("VariableOptions", Order=6)]
    public ServiceOptionType[] VariableOptions {
        get {
            return this.variableOptionsField;
        }
        set {
            this.variableOptionsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("VariableOptions");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=7)]
    public ConsolidationKey ConsolidationKey {
        get {
            return this.consolidationKeyField;
        }
        set {
            this.consolidationKeyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ConsolidationKey");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=8)]
    public RequestedShipment RequestedShipment {
        get {
            return this.requestedShipmentField;
        }
        set {
            this.requestedShipmentField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestedShipment");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2556.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v22")]
public partial class WebAuthenticationDetail : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private WebAuthenticationCredential parentCredentialField;

    private WebAuthenticationCredential userCredentialField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public WebAuthenticationCredential ParentCredential {
        get {
            return this.parentCredentialField;
        }
        set {
            this.parentCredentialField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ParentCredential");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public WebAuthenticationCredential UserCredential {
        get {
            return this.userCredentialField;
        }
        set {
            this.userCredentialField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserCredential");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2556.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
```

How do I use this newfangled code?  Why the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use this newfangled code?

You could create an instance for the service client (proxy), and invoke the service with it. For example (`ToDoService` is the namespace you defined for this service client):

```
ToDoService.RatePortTypeClient client = new ToDoService.RatePortTypeClient();
```

More details about how to you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632282/how-to-make-a-uwp-that-will-work-with-the-default-wcf-service-application).

> Why the change?

The `Reference.cs` is proxy that auto generated by tools. The sample client app you are downloading is a `ConsoleApplication` which is target `.Net framework 2.0`, but your app is a UWP app. They are different applications and target different frameworks. Even you can find the `Reference.cs` file was auto-generated by `Microsoft.VSDesigner` in the sample app, but  was auto-generated by `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceReference.Platforms` in your UWP app.