# Call restful service using button click

Tags: c#, restful-url, wcf-rest

I wish to call the get function from a button click on my web application

my code in my application is

```
protected void btngetbtanches_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:54691/") as HttpWebRequest;

            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            using (Stream branchstream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                            StreamReader loResponseStream =
            new StreamReader(branchstream, Encoding.UTF8);

            string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

            loResponseStream.Close();
            resp.Close();
            }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

in my service is

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestSerivce
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Default")]
        string GetBranchData();


    }     
}
```

}

get data is defined in  another file in the service project. When I try to click the button some html is returned and the service is not called.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does the html says?

Comment: "<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n    <title>Directory Listing -- /</title>\r\n        <style>\r\n        \tbody {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size: 8pt;color:black;} \r\n        \tp {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-

Comment: It looks like the butoon is returning the front page of the service, but not going through to getdata

Comment: I think your url is incorrect; it should at least contain `GetBranchData`

Answer (score 1):

Your web request does not match the end point of the service:

You should try:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create
        (@"http://localhost:54691/RestSerivce/GetBranchData") as HttpWebRequest;
```

or at least the one which matches your routing.

You can also add the service as reference and consume it's type, which is a common approache.

You can check this answer for more details.
[How to consume WCF web service through URL at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193124/how-to-consume-wcf-web-service-through-url-at-run-time)